# Unable to login to my router

Tags: internet

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I have reset my router. Now when I enter the IP adress of my D-Link 2730U(=192.168.1.1) in my browser(FireFox, Chromium), I get the messege `No internet connection.`

- Before resetting, the same IP adress took me to the configuration page.
- I have changed my provider recently.
- The LED that shows a globe is off.

Comment: May be it have another default IP? Like 192.168.0.1 or similar? Usually printed on bottom or back of router. Did your PC get ip by DHCP from router?

Comment: @LeonidMew the same IP worked before resetting. Unfortunately I Don't know what DHCP is.

Comment: If you never change that ip all fine. DHCP is a service on your router what gives ip addresses to connected computers, what address it gives to your PC? May be you need to change network configuration on PC, after router reset. Set IP and DNS to auto in network interface config.

Comment: I do not see how this question is related to Ubuntu. The factory default for D-Link routers is 192.168.0.1 (not 1.1). Since you reset your router, try the factory default.  If that doesn't work, then contact D-Link support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reset your router, your computer has probably lost it's own IP address.

Open a terminal and type in `ifconfig -a` to see what your own computer IP address is.  Hopefully, if you're connected by Wi-Fi, you'll see a wlan0 and it will have received an IP via DHCP from your router.  IF your router is 192.168.1.1, your computer should have an IP such as 192.168.1.2 or .3.  The default gateway should be the IP address of your router.

If not, you'll need either set a static IP address, or check that DHCP is enabled on your laptop.

Alternatively, some routers may (loosely, probably don't), but try connect an ethernet cable and see if that allows you to browse to the router config page.

The following link should guide you to set a static IP address (it also shows how to check DHCP is enabled):

[Switch To Static IP Address On Ubuntu 17.04 / 17.10](https://websiteforstudents.com/switch-static-ip-address-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/)